# Python Discord Bot problems

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to code a Python Discord bot based on Harry Potter. On my pc I use repl.it and on my laptop I use PyCharm CE.

My laptop doesn't detect the discord module. I can't reinstall or uninstall the module, because lots of different errors. An OSError is raised when trying to force reinstall. I also get "permission denied" sometimes, but I don't know how to change permissions.

On my pc, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Also, repl.it doesn't allow me to create a .env file and I can't figure out how to use Secrets (Environment Variables).

Here's the troublesome code. Note that the code is exactly the same on both platforms:

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: You don't have `import discord` here.  You can use `os.environ['TOKEN']` to fetch an environment variable.

Comment: no import discord is there, it just didnt include in the format for stackexchange when i copy pasted, but ill try that. do i include it in the code?

Comment: Since there is no `strip` call here, it's impossible for us to tell what you have done.

Comment: then i havent a clue, ill try to figure it out and update

Comment: Could you please include the full error message you get on your pc, starting from the word "traceback", into the code block I edited into the question?

Comment: @TimRoberts The `import discord` was on the same line as the start of the code block (```), so it was interpreted as the language identifier by the markdown formatter and not shown to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

In the last line, simply change `client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` to `client.run('<bot-token>')` where `'<bot-token>'` is supposed to be your actual bot token in string format. (In case you aren't sure where to find the bot token of your bot, [this link](https://www.writebots.com/discord-bot-token/) may help)

**Long answer:**

The `client.run()` function needs your bot token as the argument in string format. From the error message that you mentioned, it seems that `os.getenv('TOKEN')` is returning `None` value, and it seems internally it is trying to strip the given token and failing to strip it because `None` value doesn't have strip attribute unlike string values. Have you stored your bot token in the key `'TOKEN'` of `os.environ` in string format? Unless you are doing that, I don't think you should use `os.getenv('TOKEN')` at all. Just enter the bot token as a string, directly as the argument in `client.run()`. (In case you aren't sure where to find the bot token of your bot, [this link](https://www.writebots.com/discord-bot-token/) may help)

Btw, I am assuming that the `'''` in the end is a typo and if not then please remove it!

So, the new code would look like:

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('<your bot token>')
```

Comment: The `'''` probably was just some incorrect code block formatting, I removed it in an edit.